# Wrong data in custom LabelItemRenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder

I have custom LabelItemRenderer for List, and overriding set data function. In each data i have property 'sales' which can be true or false. Depend on this property i`m adding icon. Everything seems fine until i`m going to scroll list up down several times. Sales is true for index of list that was set to false. I check my data provider and can`t find mistakes, but in my custom item render data is wrong and icon show up at wrong place.

here is my code:

```
package components {

import flash.display.Bitmap;

import spark.components.LabelItemRenderer;
import spark.components.supportClasses.StyleableTextField;
import spark.primitives.BitmapImage;

public class StoresList extends LabelItemRenderer {

    private var storeName:StyleableTextField;
    private var floor:StyleableTextField;
    private var mapListIco:Bitmap;
    private var promotions:Bitmap;
    private var sales:Boolean;
    private var compData:Object;

    public function StoresList() {

        super();
    }


    override public function set data(value:Object):void {

        compData = value;

        storeName.text = compData.title;
        floor.text = 'floor : ' + compData.floor;

        if (compData.sales && compData.salesIco) {
            promotions = compData.salesIco;
            addChild(promotions);
        }
    } 

    private function createStoreName():void {

        storeName = StyleableTextField(createInFontContext(StyleableTextField));
        storeName.editable = false;
        storeName.selectable = false;
        storeName.multiline = false;
        storeName.wordWrap = false;
        storeName.styleDeclaration = styleManager.getStyleDeclaration(".titleStyleName");

        addChild(storeName);
    }

    private function createFloortextField():void {

        floor = StyleableTextField(createInFontContext(StyleableTextField));
        floor.editable = false;
        floor.selectable = false;
        floor.multiline = false;
        floor.wordWrap = false;
        floor.styleDeclaration = styleManager.getStyleDeclaration(".floor");

        addChild(floor);
    }


    override protected function createChildren():void {

        // store name
        createStoreName();

        // floor
        createFloortextField();

        // maplist ico
        mapListIco = new Textures.mapListIco160;
        addChild(mapListIco);
    }


    override protected function measure():void {

        measuredWidth = getElementPreferredWidth(storeName) + getElementPreferredWidth(floor);
        // We only care about the "real" ascent
        measuredHeight = getElementPreferredHeight(storeName) +  getElementPreferredHeight(floor); 
    }


    override protected function drawBackground(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {

        super.drawBackground(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    }


    override protected function layoutContents(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {

        // store name
        var gap:Number = Math.round(unscaledHeight * .1);
        var storeNameHeight:Number = getElementPreferredHeight(storeName);
        var floorHeight:Number = getElementPreferredHeight(storeName);
        var storenameY:Number = Math.round( (unscaledHeight - (storeNameHeight + floorHeight + gap) ) * .5 );

        setElementSize(storeName, storeName.textWidth, storeName.textHeight);
        setElementPosition(storeName, unscaledWidth * .15, storenameY);

        // floor
        var floorY:Number = Math.round(storenameY + storeNameHeight);
        setElementPosition(floor, unscaledWidth * .15, floorY + gap);

        // map list
        setElementPosition(mapListIco, unscaledWidth - mapListIco.width - unscaledWidth * .05, (unscaledHeight - mapListIco.height) * .5);

        // promotions
        if (promotions) {

            setElementPosition(promotions, 
                (unscaledWidth * .15 - getElementPreferredWidth(promotions)) * .5, 
                (unscaledHeight - getElementPreferredHeight(promotions)) * .5)
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

ItemRenderers are reused - so when a renderer is given new data [via set data()] you need to clear any data that is not used. In your case, you need to explicitly hide the icon (as it might have been visible the last time renderer was used). For instance:

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void {
    //always call super on an overriden function unless you have specific reason not to
    super.data = value;
    ...
    if (compData.sales && compData.salesIco) {
        promotions = compData.salesIco;
        promotions.visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        promotions.visible = false;
    }
}
```

I suggest creating promotions Bitmap in createChildren rather than in set data - as repeatedly adding and removing it is a relatively expensive operation.

Comment: Thank you, i moved creation of promotion in createChildren and hide it when new data is set. Now everything works fine.. 10x